# Fails to get only Menu Bar in a new page from the Agency bootstrap theme

Tags: html, css, themes

I am trying to create another page from the index page of Agency Bootstrap theme ,

in which the page will contain only Menu bar and its footer , but when i try to remove the

```
<header class="masthead">
```

Tag which i don't want but once i do that menu will not have background black color

**Required Result :**

[image]

**Erroneous page while creating new page**

[image]

Source : https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-agency

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to solve the color issue is to add bootstrap class bg-dark to the nav tag. another solution is to add class .color

```
.color{ background-color: #212529}
```

if You want to remove the navbar Shrink effect just delete this line of code

```
 <script src="js/agency.min.js"></script>
```